# Как с помощью регулярных выражений осуществить замену цифр

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно заменить название, состоящее из буквы и цифры на другое, также состоящее из буквы и цифры. Как с помощью регулярных выражений осуществить замену названия, состоящего из буквы и числа на другое, также состоящее из буквы и числа так, чтобы, одна цифра заменялась на саму себя с нулем перед ней, а двузначное число - само на себя?
Например, П3->SV03, П12->SV12

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то сами по себе регулярные выражения ничего не заменяют, это формальный язык, позволяющий описать какое то множество. Сама замена осуществляется при помощи языка программирования. Вас какой язык интересует?

Comment: Да, само описание и имею ввиду. 
Например, если ^П(?<num1>\d)?(?<num2>\d) заменить на SV${num1}${num2}, П3 заменится на SV3. Мне же нужно, чтобы замена произошла на SV03. А замена П11 - на SV11.

Comment: @Tamara Krasnova, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP:

```
$string = "П3, П14";
$pattern = array('/П(\d{2,})/u', '/П(\d{1})/u');
$replacement = array('SV$1', 'SV0$1');
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
// echo $result;
```

JavaScript:

```
var str = "П3, П14";
var onlyOneDigit = /П(\d{1})/g;
var twoAndMoreDigits = /П(\d{2,})/g;

str = str.replace(twoAndMoreDigits, "SV$1")
         .replace(onlyOneDigit, "SV0$1");
//console.log(str);
```

Выведет:

```
SV03, SV14
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!